# Querying temporal data in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, recurrence, temporal

There are several possible ways I can think of to store and then query temporal data in Neo4j. Looking at an example of being able to search for recurring events and any exceptions, I can see two possibilities:

One easy option would be to create a node for each occurrence of the event. Whilst easy to construct a cypher query to find all events on a day, in a range, etc, this could create a lot of unnecessary nodes. It would also make it very easy to change individual events times, locations etc, because there is already a node with the basic information.

The second option is to store the recurrence temporal pattern as a property of the event node. This would greatly reduce the number of nodes within the graph. When searching for events on a specific date or within a range, all nodes that meet the start/end date (plus any other) criteria could be returned to the client. It then boils down to iterating through the results to pluck out the subset who's temporal pattern gives a date within the search range, then comparing that to any exceptions and merging (or ignoring) the results as necessary (this could probably be partially achieved when pulling the initial result set as part of the query).

Whilst the second option is the one I would choose currently, it seems quite inefficient in that it processes the data twice, albeit a smaller subset the second time. Even a plugin to Neo4j would probably result in two passes through the data, but the processing would be done on the database server rather than the requesting client.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to use Cypher or Neo4j to do this processing as part of the initial query?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not 100% sure I understand you requirement, I'd have a look at this blog post, perhaps you'll find a bit of inspiration there: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html